# Java Oracle Documentation for JAXB Clarification (What is a Java property attribute)?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am reading through the JAXB tutorial at docs.oracle.com, and came across the following lines:

> A schema component using a simple type definition typically binds to a
>   Java property. Because there are difference kinds of schema
>   components, the following Java property attributes (common to the
>   schema components) include:
>
> - Base Type
> - Collection Type (if any)
> - Predicate
>
> The rest of the Java property attributes are specified in
>   the schema component using the *simple* type definition

I understand the first sentence.  I am completely lost after that.  What does it mean when talking about "Java Property Attributes?"

Answer (score 1):

Read it as "attributes of the Java Property". Actually, they have probably meant "properties", but "Java Property properties" is even worse that you read now.

To explain it a bit more. Schema components with simple types typically produce a Java property in your schema-derived class. This property has, well, its own characteristics, namely:

- Base type (like if it is a `xs:boolean`/`boolean`)
- If it is a collection or not (see `xs:list` constructs)
- Predicate (not sure what it is, probably `required` or `fixed`, something like this)

Hope this helps.